# I want to display HTML page and NOT display an image. But the code is trying to open an image incorrectly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image-gallery, magnific-popup

There is a jquery magnific popup gallery containing 6 pics. I want that if a user clicks on a pic he/she should be directed to an html page (embedded.html). How can I make this happen?.

Original Code (as is present now on the website):

```html
<div id="gallery" class="tm-content-box">
  <div class="grid tm-gallery">
    <figure class="effect-bubba">
      <img src="img/img-11-08.jpg" alt="Image 8">
      <figcaption>
        <h2>TEST</h2>

        <a href="img/img-11-07.jpg">View more</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
```

I modified above(index.html) as follows. ( instead of `img/img-11-07.jpg` getting displayed I want `embedded.html` to be displayed ):

```
<div id="gallery" class="tm-content-box">
  <div class="grid tm-gallery">
    <a href="embedded.html">
      <figure class="effect-bubba">
        <img src="img/img-11-08.jpg" alt="Image 8">
        <figcaption>
          <h2>TEST</h2>


        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
```

But it is still not working now. on clicking TEST it is saying `The image could not be loaded`. And if I further click on `The image` in this statement I am redirected to embedded.html successfully.

I know  there is some css interfering. Kindly help. Also let me know if you want more informaation.

I have downloaded this website as a template and I am modifying its code.

**UPDATE:**
I have uploaded the entire website code here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13IURTJWYTXgifAO72AgTwomKaFNPFDkc

Comment: There are total 4 CSS files. Is there a way that I can attach those files in here somewhere ? I am looking into this

Comment: You likely need to contact the template developer. The figure is completely handled by his code

Comment: Don't use a gallery if you do not want a gallery

Comment: I have uploaded the 4 CSS files. See question section above.

Comment: @mplungjan Actually I like the little effect that is being produced from the code. I want to keep it. It is just that I want html page to open instead of the photo when user clicks on a photo inside the gallery

Comment: The CSS isn’t really relevant here. The theme developer seems to have implemented this kind of “lightbox” functionality with JavaScript, and apparently it just looks for whatever kind of link it can find inside this container, assuming it was pointing to an actual image to display when the whole thing gets clicked. So you will have to check whether a) this can be disabled completely via the theme settings maybe, or b) there is some JavaScript somewhere triggering this that could be modified accordingly, [...]

Comment: or if nothing else works c) use different classes for those elements, so that the JS functionality does not get triggered to begin with (in that case you might have to duplicate some of the CSS, so that it still _looks_ the same.)

Comment: @CBroe Yes I think you are right. >> it was pointing to an actual image to display when the whole thing gets clicked. Yes correct. Could you please elaborate - how can I disable the javascript (option b)

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, you will have to deregister the click event handler attached by the gallery. Specifically, the click handler is attached to the `<div class="tm grid gallery">` element containing the anchor supposed to trigger the load of the html. Thus one of the following commands should do the trick, depending on how the event handler has been registered (in interactive testing using Chrome's development tools, the `unbind`call would suffice).

The `parent()` call travels to the designated `div` element among the anchor's DOM ancestors. Adjust that if you choose a different subtree structure:

```
$("a[href='embedded.html']").parent().off('click');
$("a[href='embedded.html']").parent().unbind('click');
```

As to when to call this code depends on when the gallery attaches its event handlers. I'd suggest to do that at the end of a `ready` handler.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am a beginner in HTML CSS. Can you please tell me the exact place where I have to modify the code and the new code itself. I have uploaded the entire website code. See link on top

Comment: @Syed.Waris I am sorry, I'm afraid the trial-and-error part is yours - in the end, it's your project, right? I would start with a new script element at the end of the `head` element like `<script>$.ready(document)( () => { /*insert code from above */ });`. That will be executed after the main page incl. dependent resources has completely loaded. FWIW, I could not edit the google docs you've uploaded.

Comment: +1. Thanks for your effort. Actually your strategy looks decent and elegant, but I corrected the issue in some other way (little crude way). I will improve on it as I will learn more HTML, CSS Jquery. Thanks !!